# Android cursor returns garbage data even if database is having correct information

Tags: android, cursor

I have a connection listener which gives me Collection, I have to insert these set of Strings in database with the checks that is it already exist in DB or not if not exist then insert. This listener gets called most of the time when network connection gets ON from OFF state, due to instability in network this methods gets called frequently, at this time Cursor data where I have put WHERE condition is always failed and count for the cursor returns 0. I have checked that cursor/database is getting closed or not, it is and not throwing any exception. Tried with blocking threads as well but still in 3rd or 4th call of cursor gets garbage, I have extracted the .db file and checks its entry DB data is perfectly stored in it but still return query failed.

Actually I am using asmack API to login with XMPP account and get Rosters, for Roster we have to set listener which gives presenceChanged(),entriesUpdate() etc. while network connection on/off situation entriesUpdate() method gets called and here I am checking whether the entries already exist in the database or not if not then insert, here cursor return garbage values.

Please let me know what could be the reason of getting cursor corruption? Does Android is having such issues with Cursor?

**Note:** I am not using ContentProvider

Here is the code:

```
private synchronized ArrayList<Contact> updateDBForNewEntries(int connectionIndex, Hashtable<String, String> addresses){
if(connectionIndex == NONE || addresses == null || addresses.size() <= 0)
return null;
String to = getAccountUserName(connectionIndex);
if(to == null){
return null;
}
AddressBookDBAdapter dbHelper = new AddressBookDBAdapter(context);
dbHelper.open();
String contactLookupTableName, whereClause, idColumn;           

if (connectionIndex == MAIN_INDEX) {
contactLookupTableName = AddressBookDBAdapter.TABLENAME_CONTACT_DETAILS;
idColumn = AddressBookDBAdapter.CONTACT_ID;
} else {
contactLookupTableName = AddressBookDBAdapter.TABLENAME_VCARD_LOOKUP;
idColumn = AddressBookDBAdapter.VCARD_ID;
}
ArrayList<Contact> addedContactsList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
Iterator<String> iterator = addresses.keySet().iterator();
to = Utils.trimStringWithSlash(to);

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
String mailId = Utils.trimStringWithSlash((iterator.next()).trim()).toLowerCase();

if(mailId == null || mailId.trim().length() <= 0)
    continue;

//check TO and FROM conditions
if(to.equalsIgnoreCase(mailId)){
    mailId = null;
    continue;               
}       
Utils.debugLog("*******frm update Mail Id = " + mailId);

if (connectionIndex == MAIN_INDEX) {
contactLookupTableName = AddressBookDBAdapter.TABLENAME_CONTACT_DETAILS;
whereClause = AddressBookDBAdapter.DATA_TYPE + "='"+ CONTACT_DATATYPE.IM + "' AND "+ AddressBookDBAdapter.DATA + " = '" + mailId.toLowerCase() + "'";

SQLiteCursor detailCursor = dbHelper.query(contactLookupTableName,
            new String[] { idColumn },
            whereClause, null, null, null, null);
Utils.debugLog("**** detailed cursor = " + (detailCursor != null? detailCursor.getCount():null)+"; whereclause="+whereClause);
try{
if(detailCursor != null){
if (!detailCursor.isClosed() && detailCursor.moveToFirst()) {
String searchKey = detailCursor.getString(0);
Utils.debugLog("****** mail Id already exist here="+whereClause + ";"+searchKey);                   
//TODO: Perform update operation here       
} else{
//Mail Id not exist in database so add it a a new entry
//TODO:: Perform insertion      
}
}
if(detailCursor != null && !detailCursor.isClosed())
    detailCursor.close();
}catch(Exception e){}
detailCursor = null;
} 
mailId = null;
}
Utils.debugLog("*** While loop ends " );
dbHelper.close();
to = null;
return addedContactsList;
}
```

Thank you,
Regards,
Aparna

Comment: please post some code regarding your issue.that would be easier for us to help you recognizing the problem.

Comment: Edited my question with code snippet, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
     for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {

     }
}
```

Try to use and increment cursor like this.

Comment: cursor.getCount() returns 0, so moveToFirst is false

Answer (score 0):

Not aware of Android having issues regarding Cursor.
Could you please post some code? Maybe you forgot to move your cursor to First, or your "WHERE" clause is missing something.

Comment: Attached code works fine sometimes but sometimes "detailCursor.getCount()" returns 0. I could reproduce this issue only with making connection OFF and ON.